# ASP.Net MVC Master Page architecture advice and dynamic CSS / JavaScript references?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, master-pages

I am moving into the ASP.Net MVC realm and need some thoughts / advice on architecture. In my current ASP.Net web forms application I am using a nested master page approach. I have a Main site master that exposes all of the common functionality and layout elements for the site. I then have a set of other master pages that inherit from the Main master the expose specific functionality for those sections. Examples of these nested master pages are: a master page for modal popup windows and a desktop type layout for most of the site.

Part of my architecture for the application is that CSS and JavaScript /JQuery reverences could be inserted into the masters or inherited aspx pages dynamically. I created a UI assembly that took care of building the references out. Here is some code from that project:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the class model for a css reference
/// </summary>
public class CssReference
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    public enum TypeEnum
    {
        TextCss
    }



}

//This is the collection in the Main Master
public List<CssReference> CssReferences
    {
       get;set;

    }

///this is how we would add to it from another inherited page or master
Master.CssReferences.AddRange(DefaultCssReferences());
```

I exposed a public property in my main master page that was a List (UIReference refers to wither the CSS or JavaScript reference types). This way from my inherited master or actual aspx page I could add to that collection any other JS or CSS references.

My question is, has anyone else done something similar to this in ASP.Net MVC or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: This is how I have been doing it in MVC 2.  I am not sure if there is another solution for MVC 3

Comment: I haven't found anything else other than what I described. I'll keep poking around and keep this post updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go about this by having a BaseController class that all your controllers inheirt (inheriting the regular Controller class) then in there you can set your CssReferences to a property of the ViewBag.

(Post about ViewBag Usage: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/19/ViewBagAspNetMvc3.aspx)

Just depends on where you need to set the References.

*On a side note*, MVC3 with Razor allows for nesting of Layouts in a similar way to ASP.NET Web Forms.

_layout.cshtml has a RenderBody() function

MyInnerLayout.cshtml sets its Layout to _layout.cshtml and all its HTML is then rendered into where _layout.cshtml has its RenderBody() function

Comment: Do the layouts work like master pages or do / would you apply layouts to view master pages?

Comment: Yeh the layouts work similar to master pages, obviously different syntax around content etc. Also look up Sections its similar to the contentPlaceHolder controls in Master pages.